# Swift 3 - Convert c structure sockaddr_in to CFData

Tags: swift3, unsafe-pointers

I need your help, this code does not compile anymore in Swift 3

```
//: Let's set up the `sockaddr_in` C structure using the initializer.
var sin = sockaddr_in(
    sin_len: UInt8(sizeof(sockaddr_in)),
    sin_family: sa_family_t(AF_INET),
    sin_port: in_port_t(0),
    sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: inet_addr(routerIP)),
    sin_zero: (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
)

//: Now convert the structure into a `CFData` object.
let data = withUnsafePointer(&sin) { ptr in
    CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer(ptr), sizeof(sockaddr_in))
}

//: Create the `CFHostRef` with the `CFData` object and store the retained value for later use.
host = CFHostCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, data).takeRetainedValue()
```

I have to fix the line "withUnsafePointer" but I don't know how?

I tried something like this

```
    let data = withUnsafePointer(to: &sin) { ptr in
        CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer(ptr), MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
    }
```

the compiler say I have to use withMemoryRebound but how ?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSData` has a convenient method to help you with this, and then you can take advantage of toll-free bridging to cast it to `CFData`:

```
let data = NSData(bytes: &sin, length: MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size) as CFData
```

Comment: thanks Jenny, that now compile however I got a new error

Comment: I posted my new bug here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476628/swift-3-cfhostschedulewithrunloop-crash